# WPF - group box cuts off title

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML that has a group box...

```
<Window x:Class="EliteFax.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EliteFax"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Fax" Height="363.683" Width="477.469">
    <GroupBox Header="Page Editor:" Margin="10,0"/>
</Window>
```

However, it appears like this...

[image]

Notice the 'g' is cut off.  How is this fixed?

Comment: This is just a designer thing. There should be no cutting when you actualy run the application.

Comment: Is your font scaling size set to 100% in the display options in control panel?